# PostgreSQL: Unable to create cluster due to UTF8

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

I`m trying to create DB cluster on PostgreSQL 14.1, Windows 10 Pro 19044 by following command through PowerShell:

```
.\pg_ctl.exe init -o "-E UTF8 --locale=ru_RU.UTF8 -U postgres" -D <cluster dir>
```

The creation fails with

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8: 0xd0 0xe0
```

The cluster dir does not contain any non-ASCII characters. Although it works correctly if I simply omit -E and --locale, but what the reason behind? May powershell cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You are logged into Windows as an operating system user whose name is not all ASCII characters. Log on as a Windows user with all ASCII character in the name and try again.

Comment: Initial username does not contain any non ascii characters. Also i tried your approach and got the same error. This problem happens only on concrete DELL laptop, on the exacly same laptop -E UTF8 works normally. I assume there are some confilcts between software or something broke in registry.

Comment: Then perhaps the path where you want to install or create the cluster.